# Add line break inside bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that allows me to wrap any function and insert a `debugger` statement before it is called.

It works fine, but since the bookmarklet is a single line debugger stops somewhere in the middle of a long string of code and I need to scroll to find the breakpoint.

How can I insert a new line character after the `debugger` statement so that when it's encountered the code in the console is split into two lines?

*The `\n` and literal newline character copied from a textarea into the bookmarklet don't split lines in the debugger.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is best to URL-encode a bookmarklet before storing in a bookmark. So you can have a multiline bookmarklet simply by encoding the newlines, as demonstrated by this: `encodeURIComponent("alert('line1');\nalert('line2');")`

That answers the question as you asked it, but I'm not sure if this is your real problem. If you provide example code I might be able to give further advice.

Comment: The code you provided (with `\n`) doesn't work but `encodeURIComponent` multiline contents of a textarea does make the function multiline in js debugger. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean "doesn't work". I pasted that code directly into Firefox console and it "works". I pasted the result into a bookmarklet and it "works". In any case, thanks for accepting.

Comment: By *doesn't work* i mean the code is still single-line in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

No, bookmarklets are always one-liners.

You can use the chrome debugger which has a "prettify code" option.

Another option would be not running it as a normal bookmarklet during debugging but injecting a script tag pointing to a properly formatted version of your script.